# Select a Kendo-Grid row inside C#-form

Tags: c#, kendo-grid

In a C# project I seem to have some struggles with a kendo-Grid.

Whenever I open an HTML page inside a webbrowser, I'm able to click and select items in this Kendo-Grid. The problem occurs when I open the same page in a C#-form using `System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser`.

I can not seem to figure out why this happens or how. This occurs on multiple pages using a kendo-grid.

The browser where this was tested on was IE-11.
The browser version in C# was also IE-11.

How can I select a row in e Kendo-Grid inside a C#-From?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution would be to update the version of Kendo that you're using.
I've been using `Kendo UI 2015 Q2` after I updated the kendo to `Kendo UI 2016 Q2` the problem ceised to exist.

This may not be an ultimate solution, but it does however work.